# Why does Lifehacks only allow me to ask a question every 40 minutes?

Tags: discussion

Have you ever asked a question on Lifehacks and got an error saying you have to wait 40 minutes to ask another question? Why is this happening and can it be bypassed?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Nevermind all I had to do was switch my internet connection from WiFi to mobile data. And yeah that let me bypass the 40 minute timer.

Answer (score 11):

This limitation is one intended to keep new users from spamming with low-quality questions or genuine spam.  Best is to live with it until you have enough rep it no longer applies -- bypassing it may risk moderation, which could include further restricting your ability to ask questions, among other things.